# Angular 6 - How to read angular specific attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a component on which I specify the angular i18in attribute like this:

```
<app-text i18n="meaning|description"> DeveloperText</app-text>
```

I want to be able to read this property. I have tried using ElementRef and accessing nativeElement but the attribute i18n is not a part of the DOM element when I view the source. When my app is launched the DOM looks like this:

```
<app-text _ngcontent-c0=""> DeveloperText</app-text>
```

So can I somehow read properties like this using the Angular Framework?

Comment: I have tried to use @Input() i18n; on the AppText component - but it's always undefined so it does not work. I know I can make a property on the component - but then i would replicate the content twice e.g. like this: <app-text customProperty="XXX" i18n="XXX"> DeveloperText</app-text>. I don't really want to do that unless there is really no way of reading the i18n property :)

Comment: I don't think you can access i18n property as angular compiler removes it from DOM, explained in angular documentation.

Comment: @AliShahbaz, can you send me a link of where this is explained?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#mark-text-with-the-i18n-attribute `i18n is a custom attribute, recognized by Angular tools and compilers. After translation, the compiler removes it. It is not an Angular directive.`

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ffc6e199bf92ee1e05a8814f21de2c1aa19a7184/packages/compiler/src/i18n/extractor_merger.ts#L387

Comment: Okay I can see that, thanks - but if it's not a directive what is it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
<app-text #something i18n="meaning|description">DeveloperText</app-text>
```

In your controller:

```
@ViewChild('something') fred;
```

You now have a handle on the element. If you log it like this:

```
console.log(this.fred);
console.log(this.fred.nativeElement);
```

You should find the value of the property you are interested in.

Comment: Good simple solution and easy to change when angular eventually catches up